# How to execute this command in systemd servicefile?

Tags: service, command-line-interface, sh, systemd

Ok, so I have this command that turns off my touchscreen. It works when I execute it in a root shell.

**So this works:**

```
sudo su
/usr/bin/echo $(ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | awk NR==1'{print $1}') > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
```

And then my touchscreen stops working, which is the result that I wanted.

Now I want to make a touchscreen.service file to execute this on every boot. So in the service file I include:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo $(ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | awk NR==1'{print $1}') > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
```

However it isn't working > nor throwing any errors that I've been able to catch.

I do know from earlier fidlings with .service files that I might actually need to use `/usr/bin/sh -c`, so I have also tried:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/echo $(ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | awk NR==1'{print $1}') > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind"
```

Yet this also doesn't work.. maybe because of the `awk NR==1'{print $1}'`part? I have also tried replacing it with `awk NR==1'\''{print $1}'\''`but again it fails to work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the command that is working in my root cli environment to also work as a systemd service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with,

1. The syntax of the `awk` command is just wrong. The quotes are incorrectly placed. The part `NR == 1` is part of the `awk` command to indicate the first line record in the file, i.e.

   ```sh
   awk NR==1'{print $1}'
   #  ^^^^^^^  should be within quotes
   awk 'NR == 1 { print $1 }'
   ```
2. Your sequence of `echo`, `ls` and the command substitution `$(..)` doesn't look right. You are effectively `echo`-ing the literal string `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch` (if `ls` finds the file at that path) over to the pipe and `awk` just writes that to the `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind` file which might not be your desired action. You just needed to do run the command on the file directly as

   ```sh
   awk 'NR == 1 { print $1 }' /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
   ```
3. Now that, that the `awk` command is fixed, you have two options to run the above command as part of `systemd`, either put your command in a script or run the command directly. For putting it in a script refer to the Unix.SE answer [Where do I put scripts executed by systemd units?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226535). As for running the command directly in `ExecStart`. Aside from using `/bin/sh` also use the path `/bin/awk`

So putting it together and using `/bin/` over `/usr/bin`, you can do below. This command uses `".."` over `awk` script and needs escape of `$1`

```sh
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/awk "NR == 1 { print \$1 }" /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind'
```

Comment: Ok, so I've rewarderd the bounty for your extensive answer for which I thank you! It ain't working precisely yet though. The reason I needed the ls command is that within `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch` there is a directory which has a different name on each system startum. For instance it is called `0018:04F3:262A.0001` afster system startup and `0018:04F3:262A.0002` after a reboot. But I need the write the name of that directory into `/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind`. But I'll try fiddle with your explanations and see how far I'll get.

Comment: Got it working thnx to your reply! In the end the command I needed to put in the servicefile was `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | /bin/awk "NR == 1 {print \$1}" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind'`